# DropDownList Losing DataSource on Postback on live site only

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, dotnetnuke

I have a DotNetNuke web page that uses ASP.Net controls and VB.Net code.  On page load I retrieve a DataSet that includes ALL of the users work orders.  This DataSet is used to fill an asp:datagrid.  I also retrieve a DataSets to fill combo boxes that include the retail accounts for the user, service type, order status, and retail locations.  On SelectedIndexChange for any of these dropdownlists, I create/modify  a DataGridFilter to modify the display results of the grid. I store the complete work order DataSet as a session variable.

In my development environment, I am running on the local host and everything works as expected.  When my code is released to my live site, The page loads as expected calling the SelectedIndexChange event for each of the dropdownlists as the datasource is set and bound.  But when the user makes a selection from any of the dropdownlists, the datasource for all of the dropdownlists appears to be lost.  This does not occur in the development environment.  The database on the live and developmental side appear to have the same structure and data.

```
 Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim dsStatus As DataSet
        Dim dsChangeStatus As DataSet

        If IsPostBack Then
            If Not Session.Item("WorkOrdersDS") Is Nothing Then
                m_dsWorkOrders = CType(Session.Item("WorkOrdersDS"), DataSet)
            End If

            If Not ViewState("DataGridFilter") Is Nothing Then
                m_DataGridFilter = ViewState("DataGridFilter").ToString
            End If
        Else
            ddAccount.DataTextField = "NameCity"
            ddAccount.DataValueField = "AccountID"
            LoadRetailAccounts()
            LoadLocations(CInt(Me.ddAccount.SelectedValue))
            dgWorkOrders.Attributes("SortExpression") = "LastUpdated_DT"
            dgWorkOrders.Attributes("SortASC") = "DESC"

            dsStatus = m_DL.RunSPGetDS("PRC_GSI_CSWorkOrder_Status_S")
            With ddStatus
                .DataTextField = "Status_VC"
                .DataValueField = "Status_ID"
                .DataSource = dsStatus
                .DataBind()
            End With
            Library.GSI.Library.ControlHelp.CreateBlankFirstItem(ddStatus, "All Except Withdrawn", "-1")
            Library.GSI.Library.ControlHelp.CreateBlankFirstItem(ddStatus, "All", "0")

            dsChangeStatus = m_DL.RunSPGetDS("PRC_GSI_CSWorkOrder_Status_S_CanChange")
            With ddChangeStatus
                .DataTextField = "Status_VC"
                .DataValueField = "Status_ID"
                .DataSource = dsChangeStatus
                .DataBind()
            End With

            If Me.ddAccount.SelectedItem.ToString.Substring(0, 1) = "*" Then
                CreateOrgChartFilter()
            Else
                CreateFilter()
            End If
            GetWorkOrdersList()
            LoadServiceTypes()
            BindDataGrid()
        End If
    End Sub

    What am I missing that might be different in my live and development code?
```

Comment: The DataGrid is not losing its values, though, right? Just the DropDownLists?

Comment: Yes, the datagrid does not display at all (no headers, nothing).  I kind of assumed this was because there were no values to pass to the datagridfilter because there are no values in the dropdownlists that those values would be coming from.  I know the page_load event actually calls before the selectedindex_change event but is there some event that might be happening between the two?

Comment: With more testing, it appears that the error is occurring only for select users.  This gives me the impression that the error may be driven by the data and I'm getting an unhanded NULL reference exception, but I've perused both the code and data and am at a loss.

Comment: Do you have any try-catch blocks that might be swallowing errors your users experience?

Comment: I have added different try-cath blocks during trouble shooting. My boss had me replace the datagridfilter with a return to the database on every selected index change.  I now pass all the parameters to the stored procedure and filter in the SELECT query instead of getting the FULL dataset and filtering.  The error still occurs. I am no longer using any session variables (related to this page).

Comment: The Issue is apparently related to the size of the dataset.  If I put a "TOP 175" in the SELECT clause of my Stored Procedure (to limit the size of the dataset), the Web Page functions correctly and in both cases (datagridfilter and multiple trips to database).

Comment: But did you ever capture any specific errors when using the try-catch blocks? How many rows are returned when you don't filter by "TOP 175"?  It seems more likely that the "TOP 175" is just filtering out your problematic data items than solving a size problem.

Comment: No ... I never had any errors captured.  The largest datasets I'm returning are just shy of 600 rows.  I also thought it might be the data, but I imported all of the live data to my development environment and I do not get the errors when running on localhost, only on the live site and just for the one (largest) user.

Comment: I don't know anything about DotNetNuke, so I don't know if that could be playing a role. 600 records is definitely not too much for a GridView to handle (I don't know about the old DataGrid). Maybe there is a bug for this large user in the stored procedure calls you're doing. You definitely want to look for something user-specific at this point.  Maybe even machine specific - does this user have the same problems on other computers?

Comment: I'm still not a 100% sure what the real cause of the issue was, but I solved the problem by adding paging to the datagrid.